# How to know user has logged in across app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing oauth login with Google and Facebook on android.

I'm just unsure, once logged in, how do I  know across the app activities and fragments that the user is logged in? Do I need to store some information in shared preferences? then retrieve from shared prefs when checking that info when checking?

The username and profile pic will be in the nav drawer. Esentially once logged in i need to know

IsLoggedIn
IsFacebook or IsGoogle User
Username
Profile Pic

Is shared prefs the way, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that sharedPreferences is not the way to do it, since it has got an little overhead when updating the settings.
I think you should make a LoginHandler class that servers a static volatile instance of the login manager, from which you can get the login method (if you code it) and check if the user is logged in.

Don't let the complexity of the terms set you back. It isn't that hard. Make sure to take a look at the source code of [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L676) to learn about dealing with and making proper static volatile objects.